macOS software to remove all hyperlinks from a PDF
The program which I use to annotate PDFs (Logseq) does not support selecting and highlighting hyperlinked text. I'm wondering if there is a piece of software to remove all hyperlinks from a PDF.
Edit: I found the cloud-based service avepdf.com. Local editors still seem non-existent.

I dont follow the reasoning.  Instead of finding a program that supports hyperlinks, you want to remove them and make the pdf less informative???

@RohitGupta The premise of the question is that Logseq is a good program for my usage. In the meantime (until selection is better implemented), it's preferable to strip the links.

A simple print to PDF converter should do the job as it removes all "interactive/clickable elements" such as links.

cpdf -remove-annotations in.pdf -o out.pdf (disclaimer, I wrote it) will do, assuming you don't have any non-hyperlink annotations you care about.
